# Unity .net 4.7.1 + Github Workflow

Tags: .net, github, continuous-integration

I am trying to setup a github workflow for .NET Standard 4.7.1 so that I can run FXCop for some static code analysis.

The precanned github workflows for .net all seem to target .NET Core 3.x.  Unity does not seem to support .NET Core.

Is there a way to install .NET Standard 4.7.1 with github workflows? If not, how else can I get some basic CI setup for my project (preferably free).

Answer (score 1):

My recommendation would be to use Gendarme with Unity. FXCop seems to require the Microsoft SDK, and Gendarme is Mono based.

https://www.mono-project.com/docs/tools+libraries/tools/gendarme/

Not sure how you’d hook that up to a Github workflow though.